# Domain not serving wsgi file, but the IP does

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a flask application on my droplet, which is running ubuntu, but every time I change my virtual host file to the domain, it just serves the index of /var/www/html and not the wsgi which I specified in the virtual host file. However, if I use my droplet's IP for "ServerName", it works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you need to delete the default website configuration file that was created when you installed your webserver service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Not sure what causes it, but if it's the same one I have you should be able to fix it by disabling the default virtualhost cofiguration.

```
a2dissite 000-default
service apache2 restart
```

This should leave just the .conf file necessary for your flask application.

Also you mention a droplet, so you might be following the DigitalOcean Flask tutorial.  If this is the case, don't forget to add the .conf extension to the configuration file in /etc/apache2/sites-available

Answer (score 0):

In the server terminal, enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf
```

Then replace the raw IP with the domain name.